# Magento 2 How can I stop Google to index my product image and details?

Tags: magento2, image, seo, b2b, google

I have b2b and b2c websites in my magento2 project.

Is there a want to stop Google to index my product images and details in b2b website, I don't need SEO on b2b.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Do you want to stop indexing for whole page or just image and description?

Comment: I need it for whole page, I don't want any data related to b2b website to be indexed by google. Image, Product name, Description,  price etc. But I need all for them for b2c.

Comment: Let me give you answer on it

Answer (score 3):

In admin Go to:

> Content -> Design -> Configuration

Edit **Global** settings

In **Search Engine Robots** tab:

Select **Default Robots** value to "**Noindex, Nofollow**"

Flush cache.

**In addition** You can also disallow all bots not to crawl your website by adding robots.txt in your project `root` directory and `pub` directory

`robots.txt` will contains following lines

```
User-Agent: *
Disallow: /
```

Comment: I think @fernandus is asking to disable SEO only for B2B website. So, instead of disabling it in global level, you should disable it on website level.

Comment: I have done this on Website level Content -> Design -> Configuration->B2B Website I can find both "Noindex, Nofollow" and  robots.tx options to apply for only B2B, Thank You. Is the anything I can do more to make more secure.

Comment: That's enough for your website not to index by any search index

Comment: Please mark answer correct if it is helpful to you, so that in future it would be helpful for others